# Iterating through table with rows more than 500 and 15 columns using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, dom

Here is the challenge;
how can I iterate (+change the elements properties,while doing so) over table consisting more than 500 rows using jquery/Javascript? The added challenge is that the browser is IE8.

I tried using for loop and $.each over the table... I got the thing working, but its slowing down the damn IE and throwing script error(Error: Do you want to continue this script? It may slow down your computer..bla bla bla).

The problem is not to know how to iterate and change the properties of individual columns, but how to optimize this process.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This would be probably an upvoted question at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but even there you should include some code...

Comment: Why not upgrade the browser?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you're executing a time-critical task, don't use jQuery. Every `$('.classname')` executes at least 20 jQuery lines, and especially in case of IE8, also a ton of native iterating through the document.

There's a limit for script lines executed in IE8. By default it executes one million lines, then user is asked, if he wants to continue the script. This limit is controlled by registry, but in case of a web app, it's not usefull to increase the value ofcourse.

In IE8 rendering speed is also an issue.

- Use minimal styling in general
- Try to avoid setting `innerHTML` / `innerText`, use `createElement()`
  and/or `createTextNode()` and `appendChild()` and/or `insertBefore()`
  instead.
- Avoid inline styles, rather change class names, or even use direct CSS rule manipulation instead.
- Cache elements as much as possible when using `getElementsBy/Tag/Class/Name()`.
- Use cahched `table.rows` and `table.rows[n].cells` collections where ever possible.
- Consider to show only a part of the table at a time, it makes rendering faster.

Comment: Hi @Teemu, you said not to use jquery, but for each row of the table, i am few text fields and a checkbox. When i click the checkbox, few calculations will happen and populate the text field of that row. When i click a checkbox at the header of table, it will select all the rows and make calculations at each row level and populate the text boxes. So its taking a lot of time and jquery is helpful in easy access of dom elements of table. So are there any tips to tune the performance more? As user1145009 has mentioned,i used different iterators too....

Comment: @user2182000 It's easy, but time/line expensive when you use jQuery. It's also hard to improve the performance of the code you can't see ; ). Anyway, I think you really should post your question and relevant code to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), guys there are hungry for questions just like this.

Comment: @user2182000 Maybe this [jsFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbgDh/) contains some useful tips for you. The snippet is written for modern browsers, but there are some instructions, how to write it for IE8.

Comment: Hi @Teemu, thanks for the jsFiddle. It kind of depicts the problem i was explaining here. I had to handle 500 rows with 15 cols, and the loop has to iterate through all of them (while doing some calculations on the background) and populating some of those cols. Well I tried to apply few  techniques to reduce the timing..and got it to work withing 7 secs. I know its too much but, m happy that IE isn't giving any alert to shutdown the script. Its really a performance critical function that i was implementing. Anyhow, thank u again

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried this

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     //iterate through columns
     //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
   }  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet. I used jquery, coz of its ease while coding.  However i tried to reduce the execution time of my script by following few tweaks like using for(as u said),instead of jquery's each to iterate through rows and cols. Also used local variables. Used more functions and less code in each function. optimized arrays..however d time it takes in worst case of iterating through all 500 rows and 15 cols while applying calculations, it took less than 7 seconds. Thank you again :)